# How to add arguments to a org.gradle.api.Action?

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm writing a custom Gradle plugin that registers an extension and uses [`Action`s](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Action.html) for configuring it so you can use it like

```
myExtension {
  info {
    someConfig("a") {
      // config for someConfig["a"]
    }
    someConfig("b") {
      // config for someConfig["b"]
    }
  }
}
```

Based on how much `someConfig` you define, the plugin created new Gradle tasks dynamically. I've seen some scenarios in which it'd useful to configure all `someConfig` with the same values, so instead of writing

```
myExtension {
  info {
    someConfig("a") {
     someValue = x
    }
    someConfig("b") {
      someValue = x
    }
  }
}
```

I was thinking in providing something like

```
myExtension {
  info {
    someConfig("a")
    someConfig("b")
    allConfigs { configName ->
      someValue = x
    }
  }
}
```

When trying to code it, I've used an `objectFactory` for creating instances of `Action` so I can configure the extension values

```
val allMyConfigs = mutableMapOf<String, SomeConfig>()

fun someConfig(configName: String, init: Action<in EnvironmentInfo>) {
    val myConfig = allMyConfigs.computeIfAbsent(env) { 
            objectFactory.newInstance(SomeConfig::class.java, env) 
        }
    init.execute(environmentInfo)
}
```

but since `Action` is a `(SomeConfig) -> Unit` (i.e. a function receiving a `SomeConfig` instance) I'm unable to pass the config name (an String) as param

Is there a way to create an `Action`, so it's compatible with both `build.gradle` and `build.gradle.kts` files, that receives an extra parameter and maintain the `SomeConfig` as delegate?